# Filtrations of motivic spectral sequences

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

I had a general question about motivic spectral sequences. In order to derive them we first begin with a filtration of the algebraic $K$-theory spectra. Something like this $\cdots \rightarrow W^2(X)\rightarrow W^1(X)\rightarrow K(X)$ for every smooth variety $X$ over a field. Note that after taking the homotopy groups of this filtration, induces a filtration on the algebraic $K$-groups, which I denote it by $Fil_1$. In order to derive the motivic cohomology we check the fibers of the successive maps which happen to be a simplicial group (I'm focusing on the Grayson filtration). By Dold-Kan we can assign a chain complex to it and sheafify it wrt Nisnevich topology. Now the second page of the motivic ss consists of sheaf cohomology groups of this sheafified complex. This ss converges to the algebraic $K$-group so it induces a filtration on it which I denote by $Fil_2$. Let's denote the Nisnevich sheafification of $W^i$ by $W^i_{Nis}$. If I understand the constructions correctly, $Fil_2$ should be the filtration on the homotopy groups induced by $W^i_{Nis}$s.

My question is that do $Fil_1$ and $Fil_2$ coincide? (For example if $W^i$ s do already satisfy the Nisnevich descent that would be the case). Or maybe they are not same. Do they at least coincide rationally?